# window batch file to copy data from csv to ms access

Tags: csv

I have 50 CSV files and I need to copy the data of csv files to MS Access. I am able to copy the data one csv file to MS Access manually. But I need to create a window batch file which copy the data from CSV files to MS Access and vice versa automatically?

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? StackOverflow is not meant to be a place for people to write all your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look to [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh855069.aspx) to provide the interface to your database.  Have a look [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/08/13/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-query-a-microsoft-access-database-with-a-windows-powershell-script.aspx).